# How to call a api with token

Tags: jquery, angular, get, http-headers

I have API which will be called using token.

Currently in Swagger UI, I could authenticate this api using a token

Example, if i put "Token 6ec8f4023d8148209749a1ed972xxxx" in the authorize box

See below:

[image: Authorize Box]

Which is on the right hand top, i could enter the token shown above and authenticate

[image]

After click on authenticate it appear as logged in shown below:

[image]

Now i can call api listed in swagger ui by clicking execute button, i could see the json data listed there.

[image]

The above api i need to call through angular, i know i can use get function from angular service,

could you please proved the code what should i add in header?

For eg: below there is no option to put token in header, only option is username and password. How shoould i pass token?

```
getToken() {
    let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    return this.http.post('http://myapi/api.php/user', {
      username: 'admin',
      password: 'password'
    }, { headers });
  }
```

Comment: What backend do you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Angular `Headers` to set value:

```
import {Headers} from 'angular2/http';
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append(headerName, value);
```

`headerName` you can put token and value here. Then on backend, you can retrieve the value from request header and verify it.

The better way is to implement HTTP interceptor. Create interceptor and add it into your `app.module.ts`. This attaches token each time you make HTTP request.

Comment: when i call token api , i am getting following response { "id": 356, "t": 15138632, "acl": 766, "n": "Jai New", "c": 6, "v": "6ec8f4023d8148209749a1ed972axxxx" } in the above v: "6ec8f4023d8148209749a1ed972axxxx" is what i need to put in authrisation header?

Comment: @SmartestVEGA if `v` is the name yes, and put value in the `value`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to implement an [Interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor):

```ts
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `${this.auth.getToken()}`
      }
    });

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

An Interceptor changes every HTTP-Request you do. In this case it adds the Authorization header.

Dont forget to include the Interceptor in your AppModule:

```ts
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
```

[Full Example here](https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors)

The dirty and faster way:

```ts
this.http.post('http://myapi/api.php/user', {
      username: 'admin',
      password: 'password'
    }, { headers: new Headers({'Authorization': token}) });
```

Comment: when i call token api , i am getting following response  {
  "id": 356,
  "t": 15138632,
  "acl": 766,
  "n": "Jai New",
  "c": 6,
  "v": "6ec8f4023d8148209749a1ed972axxxx"
}

Comment: in the above v: "6ec8f4023d8148209749a1ed972axxxx" is what i need to put in authrisation header?

Comment: looks like this to me, yes, but refer to your documentation of your backend